# Creating file and saving to a variable NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to crawl a website. My goal is to be able to send a screenshot image and a html file in the response.

My code will show my route receiving a url as a parameter, passing that to my crawling function, performing the proper action via Puppeteer, and returning the screenshot and (currently) html as a string. I need to turn that html string into a HTML file, without saving it, only in memory.

route file:

```
const crawler = require('./../puppeteer/crawler.js');


module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/crawl/screenshot/:url', (req, res) => {
    const url = req.params.url;
    crawler.pageScreenshot(url, function(screenshot) {
      let buffer = new Buffer(screenshot);
      let myScreenshot = buffer.toString('base64');
      // res.contentType('image/png');
      res.send(myScreenshot);
    });
  });
  app.get('/crawl/html/:url', (req, res) => {
    const url = req.params.url;
    crawler.pageHTML(url, function(html) {
      console.log(typeof html);
      let buffer = Buffer.from(html).toString('base64');
      // res.contentType('text/html');
      res.send(buffer);
    });
  });
  app.get('/crawl/screenshot_and_html/:url', (req, res) => {
    const url = req.params.url;
    crawler.pageScreenshotAndHTML(url, function(screenshot,html) {
      let buffedScreen = Buffer.from(screenshot).toString('base64');
      let buffedHtml = Buffer.from(html).toString('base64');
      let obj = JSON.stringify({'screenshot': buffedScreen, 'html': buffedHtml});
      res.contentType('application/json');
      res.send(obj);
    });
  });
};
```

crawler file:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function pageScreenshot(url, cb) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  let screenshot = await page.screenshot({fullPage: true});
  await browser.close();
  cb(screenshot);
}
async function pageHTML(url, cb) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  let html = await page.content();
  await browser.close();
  cb(html);
}
async function pageScreenshotAndHTML(url,cb) {
  // this encoding doesn't work
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  let screenshot = await page.screenshot({fullPage: true});
  let html = await page.content();
  await browser.close();
  cb(screenshot,html);
}
module.exports = {
  pageScreenshot: pageScreenshot,
  pageHTML: pageHTML,
  pageScreenshotAndHTML: pageScreenshotAndHTML
}
```

Again, my variable html (in my crawler file) is currently a string of html. I need that variable to be a HTML file with the html i'm getting from puppeteer, not just a string. I'd like to do this without saving/writing to a file locally and then have to delete that file.

Thanks!

Comment: "HTML file variable" What does this mean? A DOM variable? If you want to wrap your html string to a jQuery object you can use `cheerio` package. `const $ = cheerio.load('your_html_string');` .

Comment: @hoangdv no, i have no front end, this is all server side. You can see in my second piece of code, the crawler file: `let html = await page.content();` . This takes the pages' entire HTML and saves it to my variable "html". However at that point it is only a string. Whereas I need to get the html of the page in form of an html file, not a string.

Comment: `cheerio` is a package working in server side. I don't know what do you want, If you read html from a html file it also return a string, if you want to save the html data of the first `puppeteer` to use in next user's requests, just only keep your html string and use another DOM access package instead of `puppeteer`.

Comment: `Whereas I need to get the html of the page in form of an html file, not a string` Save this string to disk and you will get a file. But then you stated you didn't want to save it. We cannot understand what you mean by "file".

Answer (score 0):

My original idea, and issue, was that I wanted to send back 2 items - an encoded png file and a encoded html file. This would ultimately be received by a different app. Then when decoding, I thought that they would decode into the files they were in the Node app above before encoding. However now I see that even sending the png back by itself, that the receiving app still has to translate the image from string format. So my original thought and issue was no longer valid because in the receiving app, i would have to take care of translating what I received no matter how it was sent. My code has remained the same, it responds a base64 encoded png, and string(of html). I take care of translating them, from base64 decoded string format, to their proper format(PNG and HTML in this case) in the app that makes call. Sorry for the confusion!